# Product of $k$ distinct positive integers is divisible by its sum

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for every positive integer $k, n$ satisfying $2 \leq k \leq n$, there exist $n$ distinct positive integers such that the product of any $k$ integers selected from those $n$ integers is divisible by the sum of that $k$ integers?

It can be seen that the statement is true for $n = k$ with $k+1$ is not a prime (for example, choose $1, 2, ... , k$ , we have $k!$ is divisible by $1+2+..+k$),
 however I cannot proof or find any $n$ different positive integers that satisfy the statement with $n > k$ or $k+1$ is a prime.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @Jam I don't know. Was it already asked in this community?

Comment: I don't know whether it's been asked. I was asking where you found it because that could lead to an existing proof. Did you come up with the problem yourself?

Comment: @Jam I think so.

Comment: One idea might be to go through each $n$ to find a solution until you can't find a set that fulfils the criteria. For $n=2$, you could use $\{6,12\}$. I'm trying to find a solution for $n=3$ but haven't so far.

Comment: @quasi I'm not sure those solutions both work? $(3+12)\nmid3\cdot12$ and $(4+20)\nmid4\cdot20$.

Comment: @JamL I misread the conditions.

Comment: $30,60,120$. $(30)(60)/(90)=20$, $(30)(120)/(150)=24$, $(60)(120)/(180)=40$.

Comment: Another one for $(k,n)=(2,3)$ is $15,30,60$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, Mathwriter?

Comment: Earth to Mathwriter, come in, please.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $a_1a_2\cdots a_k$ is not divisible by $a_1+\cdots+a_k$. You can fix it by choosing $d$ such that $(a_1d)(a_2d)\cdots(a_kd)$ is divisible by $a_1d+\cdots+a_kd=(a_1+\cdots+a_k)d$. So for each set of $k$ of your $n$ numbers there a multiplier $d$ that fixes it. Take any common multiple of all these values of $d$, and multiply all the $a_i$ by it, and you've fixed everything.

Comment: (+1) As a side-note, if I'm not mistaken, you can transform this answer into **@quasi's** answer by defining $d=a_1+\ldots+a_k$, for each subset $\{a_1\ldots a_k\}$. This would fulfil your criteria. And then the product of each $d$ over all subsets would be @quasi's "$a$" or your "common multiple".

Answer (score 4):

Fix positive integers $k,n$ with $2\le k \le n$.

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be any $n$ distinct positive integers, and let $a$ be the product of all sums of $k$-element subsets of $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$.

Define $y_1,...,y_n$ by $y_i=ax_i$.

Then the product of any $k$ elements of $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ is a multiple of $a^2$, hence is a multiple of the sum of those $k$ elements.